# ForEach is retrieving wrong value in SwiftUI LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI LazyVGrid with a ForEach loop.  I wanted to add buttons to each item in the LazyVGrid, and then process either an Edit, View, or Delete based on user selection.  The Delete Buttonappears to work OK, but the NavigationLink’s for Edit and View seem to return a random object in the ForEach loop.

```
var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, alignment: .center, spacing: 1) {
                        ForEach(events, id: \.self) { event in
                            HStack {
                                VStack {
                                    ZStack {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Image(uiImage: (event.cardFrontImage ?? blankCardFront)!)
                                        HStack {
                                            VStack {
                                                Spacer()
                                                Text("\(event.event ?? "")")
                                            }
                                        }
                                        VStack {
                                            HStack {
                                                Spacer()
                                                NavigationLink(destination: EditAnEvent(event: event, recipient: recipient), isActive: $isEditActive, label: {
                                                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                                                })
                                                NavigationLink(destination: CardView(cardImage: (event.cardFrontImage ?? blankCardFront)!, event: event.event ?? "Unknown Event", eventDate: event.eventDate! as Date), isActive: $isCardActive, label: {
                                                    Image(systemName: "doc.text.image")
                                                })
                                                Button(action: {
                                                    areYouSure.toggle()
                                                }, label: {
                                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                                })
                                                .confirmationDialog("Are you Sure", isPresented: $areYouSure, titleVisibility: .visible) {
                                                    Button("Yes") {
                                                        withAnimation {
                                                            print("Deleting Event \(String(describing: event.event))")
                                                            deleteEvent(event: event)
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    Button("No") {
                                                        withAnimation {
                                                            print("Cancelled delete of \(String(describing: event.event))")
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(height: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                            .background(Color(.systemGray5))
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 20)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .accentColor(.green)
```

I’ve removed as much formatting to reduce the number of lines, and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You make a commun mistake that the same areYouSure.’c’, isEditActive bool are used for all cell in your grid : only the first link will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking the Views up should help fix it. E.g. put the delete button and confirmation in its own View.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the id: \.self as the data is store in CoreData with a id: UUID?.  However, when I load the view now, I get only the first value.. Looking at my code I see that I never initialized the id in the initial save.  I am sure that will fix it.

Comment: Oh if event is a core data object then it already implements Identifiable so you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Looks like breaking it into a separate view for the menu overlay did fix it!  Thanks to PtitXav and malhal for the points